# Remove quotes from csv before inserting into database

Tags: php, string, sql-server-2008, parsing

I have a csv that looks similar to the below

```
"0","Task 1","456461608"
"0","Task 2","483727014"
"1","Task 3","277047414"
```

I have the following php code ($prep simply writes the data in the array to the db)

```
$csv_array = file($file_name);
foreach ($csv_array as $row_num => $row) {
    $row = trim ($row);
    $column = explode ( ',' , $row );
    $param1 = $column[2];
    $param2 = $column[1];
    $param3 = $column[0];

    // insert the row
    $result = execute ( $prep );
}
```

I need to remove the quotes around the first column ($param3) and the last column ($param1). What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Why aren't you using fgetcsv() to do this for you? - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: mostly because I didn't know it existed, and now that I know it exists, I don't know how to use it to write to sql

Comment: You don't use fgetcsv to write to SQL, same as you don't use explode to write to SQL.... you use the MySQLi or PDO functions to do that, and that's a totally different question

Answer (score 2):

PHP has [csv specific functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). You should use them as they take care of the issues you are facing, i.e., what if the column value contains quotes. Also:

`$column = explode ( ',' , $row );`

What if one of the columns contains a comma in its value?

The csv functions will ensure the data is parsed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an array is too dumb to get the job done. [Some objects](http://php.net/splfileobject) are more clever:

```
$rows = new SplFileObject($path);
$rows->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(1) "0"
  [1]=> string(6) "Task 1"
  [2]=> string(9) "456461608"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(1) "0"
  [1]=> string(6) "Task 2"
  [2]=> string(9) "483727014"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(6) "Task 3"
  [2]=> string(9) "277047414"
}
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/16455)